# Changing formatting of biblatex citations that have a custom shorthand

Tags: biblatex

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
    
  @inproceedings{Duck23,
    author = {Donald F. Duck},
    title = {How to get away with Scrooge},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 42nd International Conference of Fictional Characters},
    year = { 2023 },
    shorthand = { ICFC~23 }
  }
    
  @inproceedings{Mouse99,
    author = {Mickey Mouse},
    title = {Dealing with Pete for fun and profit},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 18th International Conference of Fictional Characters},
    year = { 1999 }
  }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

Our previous work~\cite{Duck23} differs from others in the literature~\cite{Mouse99}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It results in something like this:

[image: screenshot]

I'm writing a cover letter for an application when I cite both works in the literature and my own publications. My publications have a shorthand that recalls the conference or journal were they appeared (like `[ICFC 23]` in the MWE). However it is not always easy to distinguish citations that are mine from literature citations. So I would like to typeset them differently, maybe in bold, or italic, or whatever.

So is there a way to tell `biblatex` to change the formatting of only the citations that have a custom shorthand?